# can't instantiate class; no empty constructor

Tags: java, android

I have the following code where I want to make a scratch effect:

```
public class Test extends View {
    public Test(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    private boolean isMove = false;
    private Bitmap bitmap = null;
    private Bitmap frontBitmap = null;
    private Path path;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Paint paint;

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (mCanvas == null) {
            EraseBitmp();
        } 
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);  
        mCanvas.drawPath(path,paint);//Draw a path
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }   

     public void EraseBitmp() {

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(),getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

        frontBitmap = CreateBitmap(Color.GRAY,getWidth(),getHeight());//The production of grey.

    //Set the brush style
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);//Set the brush style: Hollow
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));//Display mode settings when photo cross
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);//Anti according to tooth
        paint.setDither(true);//Anti jitter
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);//Set the joint appearance, ROUND arc
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(20);//Set the stroke width

        path = new Path();

        mCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);//Set up a band picture of canvas
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(frontBitmap, 0, 0,null);
    }

          @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            float ax = event.getX();
            float ay = event.getY();

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                isMove = false;
                path.reset();
                path.moveTo(ax, ay);
                invalidate();
                return true;
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                isMove = true;
                path.lineTo(ax,ay);
                invalidate();
                return true;
            }
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
          public  Bitmap CreateBitmap(int color,int width, int height) {
            int[] rgb = new int [width * height];

            for (int i=0;i<rgb.length;i++) {
                rgb[i] = color;
            }
            return Bitmap.createBitmap(rgb, width, height,Config.ARGB_8888);
        }
}
```

and the manifest file where i declare the class is:

```
  <activity
            android:name=".Test"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

When i want to compile is gives the above error: can't instantiate class; no empty constructor
I added an empty constructor but no success. I am a newbie so please be patient. I searched the net but couldn't get a solution.

And the xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Thanks for your patronage"
            android:background="#000"
            />

        <com.example.winter.carrefour.Test
        android:id="@+id/eraseView1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

> When i want to compile is gives the above error: can't instantiate class; no empty constructor I added an empty constructor but no success

There's no required constructor in code you posted. You got only one, while you need three:

```
public Test(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public Test(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public Test(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
```

**EDIT**

> Test; no empty constructor

Empty constructor is this:

```
public Test() {}
```

however it smells that you try to use this View wrong way. Aren't you trying to use it as fragment by any chance?

Comment: 03-10 12:11:38.267: E/AndroidRuntime(11990): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.winter.carrefour.Test; no empty constructor

Comment: Aren't you trying to use it as fragment by any chance? Show the layout where you use this Test view

Comment: are you sure the code you posted is the same code that is being used? Maybe you copied the class file and you edit the copy? You must update the question whit the whole class code, incl. `package`. In fact you can strip anything but constructors as this is irrelevant

Comment: this is the whole code I use. only that class and the xml.

Comment: no, this is not the whole content of your class file.

Answer (score 0):

You have only 1 constructor create additional ones and will be fine

```
public Test(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

public Test(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

public Test(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Test class has only one Constructor

this:

```
public Test(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

you need the default one (the constructor taking no parameters)